# Calculation when number is 999999999999999

Tags: javascript, numbers, calculation

After I read [#magically-increasing-numbers](https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs#magically-increasing-numbers),

so I was wondering about If made **calculator** with JS how and user put a **large number** like `9999999999999999`

```js
const result = 9999999999999999 + 2
console.log(result)
```

**Correct result** should be `10000000000000001` not `10000000000000002`

I tried with `Number()` or even `parseFloat()` but still does not work.

How we can deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already discovered, you ran into an issue with the limited precision of floating point numbers, since your number is outside of the range of "safe integers" which are stored with full precision (it is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` = 2^53 - 1).

If you only need integers, the [native `BigInt` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) will work just fine (as long as you take care of converting things to/from a `BigInt` in the right way):

```js
const result = 9999999999999999n + 2n
console.log(result) // 10000000000000001n (not printed in Stack Overflow somehow)
```

If you need decimals too, then you will need a library handling arithmetics with big arbitrary-precision decimals, such as [`bignumber.js`](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/), to name one of many.